# Failed to instantiate module ngJoyRide

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-injector

I am using `ng-joyride` for the first time.
I did `bower install ng-joyride --save`. And included it in my modules along with other modules like :

```
angular.module('some', [  'ionic','ngJoyRide','ui.router',])
```

And now I am not able to see the view part of my app. And the console says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
and
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module XYZ due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed`enter code here` to instantiate module main due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngJoyRide due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngJoyRide' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

But before including ngJoyRide, I didn't get any issue with Jquery.
    script tag with jquery in my index.html looks like :

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

I sense this might be a very silly mistake done by me. But not sure where I went wrong, help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is hard to read b/c  you've wrapped your comments in code.

Comment: Hii @AndyWiesendanger , thanks for the response and am sorry if the code was not readable!! This is the first time I am asking a question with code !! :D . And just the issue got fixed. The problem is the path of ngjoyride.js was not automatically included in index.html. Restarting the gulp did the trick! One of my friends suggested that!

Comment: Good to hear. You can delete the question then, as it probably won't help any others.

Comment: 0h yeah!! I will. :) @AndyWiesendanger